Can mantras in Buddhist meditation be recited in translation, or does it need to be recited in Sanskrit?
I'm referring to Mantras listed here such as the Shakyamuni Mantra:

Om Muni Muni Mahamuni Shakyamuniye Svaha

In Buddhist practice throughout the world, what is the predominant practice: are those mantras translated into the local language or do adherents recite them in the original Sanskrit?
If one can choose, is there any spiritual benefit from reciting them in Sanskrit during meditation?

A lot of the ancient Buddhist texts had been translated ages ago when they were transmitted to other countries and cultures such as the Chinese civilization. An example is Gate Gate Para Gate Parasam Gate Bodhi Svaha in Chinese as 揭谛、揭谛，波罗揭谛，波罗僧揭谛，菩提萨婆诃.
Frankly, I would encourage understanding the meanings and intentions behind these mantras as illustrated in the answers to this question. Often, as our practice deepened, we began to understand and resonate with many of these once obscure words. Why Bhagavato? Why Arahato? Why Gate? It is like the saying, "Love is bittersweet".
As children, we are clueless. As teenagers, after our first romance, it begins to reveal its meaning. Then as adults who had been through a few relationships, it takes on another meaning. Later as we grow older and reminisce about past relationships, yet another dimension reveals itself. All these insights and experiences teach us how to better handle and manage ourselves, others and our relationships. In short, to be a better human.
is there any spiritual benefit from reciting them in Sanskrit during meditation?
I am not sure about the spiritual benefits in reciting these mantras in a particular language. But I am quite confident about the certainty (in the practice) and the inspiration that one gets when our insights and experiences resonate with the meanings behind those words in the mantras.
Therefore, we don't need lots of mantras, just select the ones that our mind naturally attracts and affiliates to. Then, work hard on our practice to realise the meanings behind our selected mantras.

Mantra(s) just translates as "mind protection" they are used to focus the mind on a mental object, the mantra. Best used when a klesha is (trying to) taking control and to avert the mind to a "holy object", a mantra.
They are not needed, just a tool.
I myself started using sanskrit mantras in the beginning of my studies but as the kleshas take less and less control I did not need to use them. Now I use more personal expresions rather than mantra, even as simple as "STOP!" (stop thinking about the mental process of clinging)
There are sect/practices that use simple "seeing, hearing, thinking" as mantras in satiphatanna practice. I think even zen use some sort of similar mindfulness mantras of "seeing, hearing" etc though I am not too versed in zen sects.
So the mantras themselves have no "power" they are just words.
I was taught that they are "special" and "holy" words because they are what "the buddha used" but in reality the Buddha didn't speak in sanskrit, avelokitishvara (for example) is a fictional personification and religious rites and practices are just a fetter one will be free of. So "Om mani padme hum" is just a simple, rather useless platitude.
As for the translation, these sanskrit mantras often translate into nonsense basically. Like Om mani padme hum translates as something like "behold the gazer of compassion" or some crap like that. (not a direct quote) they are just nonsense words, again to be used as a tool.
So yeah, use them as you need but don't feel that you need to use them as well as need to use the sanskrit translations or any specific thing as a mantra. Personally I would suggest to use something that is completely personal to the individual mediator (you)
Fun fact, when I was studying in a (tibetan) mahayana sect I was doing the 100 syllable vajrasattva mantra recitation. Doing it constantly every day in my mind for at least a month in preparation for a tantric empowerment. Anyway I messed up the last word. So I would do it all correctly but at all the time I what pronouncing the last word, spelt "phat" as "fat" when the correct pronunciation is "pay" anyway, I already knew of a story and my teacher also explained that the faith itself from doing the mantra is what matters, not the actual recitation. Story being similar where a person did one hundred thousand recitations of the wrong mantra but became enlightened anyway (just a fable)
